# Android: create a listview that covers half the screen and updates itself

Tags: java, android, list, listview, arraylist

I'm writing an app in which you enter a few letters and it creates a list of words that use those letters in that order (but not necessarily consecutively).

I would like my listview to only take up the screen underneath the text entry field and two buttons (the text field and buttons are in a linearLayout and on the top of the screen not taking up much room).

Also, I have an arrayList of all the words I want to show in the list but I don't know how to make it update with the new arrayList each time the search function is invoked.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Also may you might want to check out adding a header to the list view... something like...

```
    lv = getListView();
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.myheader,
            lv, false);
    lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with headers but I could figure it out. So the header would be the text box and buttons?

Comment: Yes, The header can be a separate layout that you create and can have anything inside of it and take up as much space as you would like. This would however not scroll with the listview it will stay in one place.  Not to difficult to implement if you just search around for it.

Comment: of course, did you figure out how to update it? if so would you mind marking this as the answer I would also appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put your first LinearLayout (the small form) and the ListView in a second LinearLayout (vertical).

Then for your data, you can use an ArrayAdapter (or extend it but it seems like your list item layout should be simple so no need really) to link your array to the ListView, and you should be able to find adequate methods in that class among : notifyDataSetChanged(), getFilter(), various methods to update the inner adapter ArrayList etc.

Comment: I just called `setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, words));` again (it's what I originally used to set up the list) and that repopulates it well. Is that an acceptable way to do it or is there a more effective or efficient way?